# How to start an application from a remote server using WMIC

Tags: batch-file, automation, windows-7

In Windows 7 I am trying to open an application on a remote server I do not want to use Powershell nor PSexec. I tried to open Firefox on a remote server using the following code but I receive a `ReturnValue = 0` but Firefox never launches.

```
WMIC.exe /node:ComputerName process call create "cmd.exe /C C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

ReturnValue = 0

Comment: have you considered the space in your path?

Comment: If you are referring between /C C: There is already a space I also added another space I still get the same error code.

Comment: He's talking about the space between `Program` and `Files`.  But a more graceful solution might be to launch it like `wmic /node:computername process call create "cmd /c start firefox"`.  Using `cmd`'s internal `start` command will locate Firefox within App Paths, so you don't have to specify the full path\\to\\executable.

Comment: I have removed the space between Program and files that didn't work. I also tried your code that still didn't work.  Both cases Return value is 0 but Firefox fails to launch.

Comment: We never advised you to remove the space.  And does the account you're logged into Windows with on  your Windows 7 box also  have admin rights on the server?  If not, you might need to add the `/user:` and `/password:` switches to your `wmic` command.

Comment: How do you know firefox has failed to launch. It will be invisible.

Comment: `wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"` will start firefox visible on local computer. If computer is not local it will be invisible.

Comment: I meant, there is a space in your path, you need to double quote your path.. You could simply remove the `cmd /c` part. `wmic /node:server process call create "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"` which leaves the entire path quoted and will start firefox.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that the spawned `cmd` process can't find a program named `c:Program`.  This is because you haven't quoted to keep the full path as a single token, and you haven't escaped your backslashes.

To fix your existing line, add backslash-escaped quotation marks around the path to Firefox.  Also, literal backslashes must be doubled in wmic's WQL arguments.

```js
wmic /node:server process call create "cmd /C \"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\""
```

An even better solution, though, would be to use `cmd`'s internal `start` command to find Firefox within App Paths so you don't have to specify the full path\to\executable.

```js
wmic /node:server process call create "cmd /c start firefox"
```

Comment: I have used your code with the double back slashes it did not work. Return value = 0

Comment: @drive Return Value = 0 is expected.  That means no error.  Is the server logged into its desktop?  Are you attempting to launch Firefox with the same user account as is logged into the server's desktop environment?  Are your computers members of a domain?

Comment: I am able to stop services and restart them remotely. I do have access. The server is on the desktop. I am using the same user account which is Administrator. Both servers are on the network.

Comment: 0 means `cmd` started. Why are you calling it as you wish to call firefox? All remote programs are invisible. How do you know it's not starting?

Comment: You are right Firefox was running invisible but what I am trying to do is launch the program. Firefox is an example.

Comment: How haven't you achieved that?

Comment: @drive Are you asking how to launch an application interactive to the remote computer's Desktop? That's [not really allowed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-remotely-start-an-interactive-process/). I'm pretty sure the only way you'll be able to hack a workaround is with a run-once scheduled task. I really don't feel like figuring out the syntax for you, though. Just do `schtasks /?`, go through the list of switches, write down the ones you need, and plug the command into a `wmic /node:server process call create` with lots of trial and error. Best of luck!

Comment: If the application is running on the background the user doesn't see it so they can't use it.  Ideally I would like the program to run so the user can interface with it.

Comment: You can use PSExec.

Comment: Problem using PsExec the program is minimized and not on the desktop.